# Detect resource loading error

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing an smartphone app loading a webview. Sometimes, because of networks problems (internet suddenly lost or too slow), all resources are not loaded (images, sound...). I know there is ways to know when a html page finish loading (`onLoad`,...), but I do not know what they do on the specific case where one of the resource failed to load because of network problem. And I can't find a way to manually test it.

Is it possible, when a html document is done loading, to know if any resources could not be loaded for any reason ? I precise that I do not know the specific content of the html.

For instance, is the `onLoad` event of the body fired in that case? Does the `document.readyState` switch to "complete"?

Comment: `window.onload` event fired when all resources are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no way to test it directly, but you can try to explicitly load the images then listen for events:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    alert('Okay');
}
img.onerror = function(){
    alert('Nope');
}   
img.src = "something.png";
```

One interesting (if maybe ugly) hack you can use if you want to, say, preload sounds or scripts into the cache for using later, is that you can ask the browser to load it as an image, as above; as long as it exists and downloads, it won't cause an error, even though it's not something displayable; most importantly, it will be correctly stored in the cache, so you can use it almost immediately.

Comment: I cannot do that in my case. I have no control over the content of the page.

Comment: Well, if you really need it, you could scan the page to find which images you're using, and then use the technique above. If the image was already loaded, it will hit the cache and immediately call onload; if it wasn't loaded, the browser will try to reload it and fire the relevant event according to the result. It could even be used to repair partially loaded images.